# In the 'category of abelian groups', how many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ are there in that category?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-groups

Question as in title. How should I think of the category of abelian groups ($\mathbb{Z}$-modules)?

I think this can relate to whether or not it is small(whether or not 'all abelian groups' form a set). Personally I think they don't, if they do form a set, then what should be the cardinality of the 'subset' of all abelian groups that are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$? It can be any cardinality because we can have any cardinality of copys of $\mathbb{Z}$ at a same time but call them different groups.

Other than that, is 'the category of sets'(let's call it $\mathcal{A}$) essentially small, i.e. equivalent to any small category? Suppose we have a category $\mathcal{B}$ that contains precisely one set for each cardinality, and let the morphisms be any possible set maps between two sets, then is $\mathcal{A}$ equivalent to $\mathcal{B}$? Is $\mathcal{B}$ small?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134109/discussion-on-question-by-yuan-yang-in-the-category-of-abelian-groups-how-man).

Comment: Any set has (usually a lot of) abelian group structures, so obviously the category of abelian groups is far from being small (it is "bigger" than the category of sets). Your second question basically amounts to "do cardinal numbers form a set?", and the answer is a big no.